# Custom markerInfoWindow is not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Custom marker info window is not appearing when didTapAtMarker return true. Info window is appearing properly when didTapAtMarker return false. I don't want to centered the clicked marker and info window should appear. Please help

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the Google Map's marker info thingy. You can try to create your own marker info view though.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for your help...I will try to create info window at clicked coordinate on map